# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException when closing NamedPipeClientStream

Tags: c#, socketexception, first-chance-exception

After I try to close a pipe client, I see the following error in the output console:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll

What does it mean? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx for an explanation of the "first chance exception".

> **What is a first chance exception?**
>   When an application is being debugged, the debugger gets notified whenever an exception is encountered  At this point, the application is suspended and the debugger decides how to handle the exception. The first pass through this mechanism is called a "first chance" exception.
>
> Depending on the debugger's configuration, it will either resume the application and pass the exception on or it will leave the application suspended and enter debug mode. If the application handles the exception, it continues to run normally.